# Асинхронность веб сокетов в nodejs. Как правильно сделать?

Tags: node.js

Есть такой код:

```
ws.on('message', function(){
    if(flag==true) {
        flag=false;
        // много кода
    }
    flag=true;
});
```

Задача такая: нужно, чтобы код в коллбеке ни при каких обстоятельствах не выполнился в параллель. То есть если клиент сделает еще один запрос до того как выполнится код в коллбеке, то этот второй запрос не должен выполнить код впараллель. Для этого и используется переменная flag. Но это только пример. Допустим что запросы от клиента придут один за другим практически одномоментно, и проверка if(flag==true) выполнится для обоих тоже одномоментно, еще до того как flag станет false. В этом случае код запустится в параллель. Так вот вопрос: может есть какие-то приемы или дополнительная функциональность для предотвращения подобного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Допустим что запросы от клиента придут один за другим практически
>   одномоментно, и проверка if(flag==true) выполнится для обоих тоже
>   одномоментно, еще до того как flag станет false

Это невозможно. node.js однопоточный. Получение и обработка следующего запроса возможны только после завершения текущего синхронного блока.

Почитайте про event loop в node.js. Запросы обрабатываются не параллельно. Они ставятся в очередь на обработку, а потом выполняются последовательно.